# Magento243: How to show order number in Gift Card Account Grid?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

**How i can show order increment id on Gift Card Account Grid**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here are the simple steps to do that**

> Izanova\GiftCardAccountColumn\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer;

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Izanova\GiftCardAccountColumn\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer;

use Exception;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Context;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\GiftCardAccount\Model\ResourceModel\History\CollectionFactory;

class OrderNumber extends AbstractRenderer
{
    protected CollectionFactory $giftCardAccountHistory;
 
    private ManagerInterface $messageManager;

    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $giftCardAccountHistory,
        ManagerInterface $messageManager,

        Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->giftCardAccountHistory = $giftCardAccountHistory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
    }

    public function render(DataObject $row)
    {
        $search = 'Order #';
        $value = '--';
        try {
            $giftCardHistoryCollection = $this->giftCardAccountHistory->create()
                ->addFieldToFilter('giftcardaccount_id', $row->getId())
                ->addFieldToFilter('additional_info', ['like' => '%' . $search . '%']);
            if ($giftCardHistoryCollection->getData()) {
                $value = rtrim($giftCardHistoryCollection->getData()[0]['additional_info'], '.') . " , ";
                $value = substr($value, strpos($value, '#') + 1);
            }
            return rtrim($value, ' ,');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage('Error:' . $e);
        }
        return $value;
    }
}
```

> Izanova/GiftCardAccountColumn/view/adminhtml/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.gift.card.account.grid.container">
            <referenceBlock class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid" name="gift.card.account.grid">
                <referenceBlock class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\ColumnSet" name="adminhtml.logging.archive.grid.columnSet">
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="adminhtml.logging.archive.grid.columnSet.ordernumber" as="ordernumber">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Number</argument>
                            <argument name="renderer" xsi:type="string">Izanova\GiftCardAccountColumn\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\OrderNumber</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </referenceBlock>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```